# NullPointerException thrown on flush after upgrading to Hibernate 4.1.3 Final

Tags: java, hibernate

I have just completed an upgrade from Hibernate 3.6 to 4.1.3 Final and at first everything seemed to go fine. However, one of my colleagues recently tested this an in one scenario he gets a NullPointer being thrown from within Hibernate (and this exception was not being thrown before we upgraded for the exact same DB). It is an incredibly strange scenario. We have an entity called BlogPost that looks like the below and it extends some mapped superclasses (that I have also included):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "blog_post")
public class BlogPost extends CommunityModelObject implements HasFeedPost {

    @Lob
    private String title;
    @Lob
    private String content;
    @Enumerated
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private CBlogPost.Status status = CBlogPost.Status.UNPUBLISHED;
    // Reference to the feed post that indicates that this blog post has been published
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "feed_post_id")
    private FeedPost feedPost;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "posted_by_employee_id")
    private Employee postedBy;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public CBlogPost.Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(CBlogPost.Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Override
    public FeedPost getFeedPost() {
        return feedPost;
    }

    @Override
    public void setFeedPost(FeedPost feedPost) {
        this.feedPost = feedPost;
    }

    public Employee getPostedBy() {
        return postedBy;
    }

    public void setPostedBy(Employee postedBy) {
        this.postedBy = postedBy;
    }
}


@Filter(name = "tenantFilter", condition = "(tenant_id = :tenantId or tenant_id is null)")
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class CommunityModelObject extends ModelObject {

    @IndexedEmbedded(prefix = "tenant", indexNullAs = IndexedEmbedded.DEFAULT_NULL_TOKEN)
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tenant_id")
    protected Tenant tenant;

    public Tenant getTenant() {
        return tenant;
    }

    public void setTenant(Tenant tenant) {
        this.tenant = tenant;
    }

    /**
     * If the Tenant is null then it can be accessed / viewed by the entire "community" / user base
     */
    public boolean isCommunityObject() {
        return tenant == null;
    }
}


@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class ModelObject extends BaseModelObject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Override
    public long getId() {
        return (id == null ? 0 : id);
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = (id == 0 ? null : id);
    }
}


@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseModelObject implements java.io.Serializable {

    // This annotation ensures that a column is not associated with this member (simply omitting the @Column annotation is not enough since
    // that annotation is completely optional)
    @Transient
    private boolean doNotAutoUpdateDateUpdated = false;

    @Version
    protected int version;
    @Column(name = "date_created")
    protected Date dateCreated;
    @Column(name = "date_updated")
    protected Date dateUpdated;

    public abstract long getId();

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public Date getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    public Date getDateUpdated() {
        return dateUpdated;
    }

    /**
     * This will set the dateUpdated to whatever is passed through and it will cause the auto update (pre-update) to NOT occur
     *
     * @param dateUpdated
     */
    public void setDateUpdated(Date dateUpdated) {
        doNotAutoUpdateDateUpdated = true;
        this.dateUpdated = dateUpdated;
    }

    public void touch() {
        // By setting date updated to null this triggers an update which results in onUpdate being called and the nett
        // result is dateUpdated = new Date()
        dateUpdated = null;
    }

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        dateCreated = new Date();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    protected void onUpdate() {
        if (!doNotAutoUpdateDateUpdated) {
            dateUpdated = new Date();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        long id = getId();

        if (id == 0) {
            return this == obj;
        }
        //Use Hibernate.getClass() because objects might be proxies
        return obj != null &&
                obj instanceof BaseModelObject &&
                Hibernate.getClass(this) == Hibernate.getClass(obj) &&
                getId() == ((BaseModelObject)obj).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        Long id = getId();
        return id == 0 ? super.hashCode() : id.intValue();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName() + "-" + getId();
    }
}
```

The strangest thing is happening when I query BlogPost in some scenarios. If I run the query below, for example, in isolation then it works fine but if I run it in amongst a bunch of other queries then I get the exception below:

```
select b from BlogPost b

java.lang.NullPointerException
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.isUpdateNecessary(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:240)
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:163)
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:225)
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:99)
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:55)
   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1153)
   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1208)
   at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
   at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:256)
```

Now the kicker is that if I take all of the fields from all of the mapped superclasses that I listed above and put them directly into BlogPost and make BlogPost just extend nothing and implement java.io.Serializable then everything works perfectly. This leads me to believe that the bug is either related to mapped superclasses or the Hibernate filter that I am applying to CommunityModelObject.

Any ideas as to how to solve this? I am assuming that it is a newly introduced bug in Hibernate but I may be wrong. This is causing major issues for us since we need to upgrade asap in order to upgrade Hibernate Search which we need to do for a critical bug fix.

Also note that the DB we are using is MySQL with the following custom dialect that I wrote when doing this upgrade to handle our BIT columns:

```
public class MySQL5InnoDBDialectExt extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect {

    private static final String BIT_STRING = "bit";

    public MySQL5InnoDBDialectExt() {
        super();
        registerColumnType(Types.BOOLEAN, BIT_STRING);
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Brent

Comment: Just an FYI, I posted this on the Hibernate forum as well: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1015428

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sorted this issue out, found the problem by fluke. Here is the resolution as I posted it on the Hibernate forum:

> I found the issue. It does not seem to be related to interceptors,
>   rather to either caching or instrumentation. Basically our app
>   automatically includes all entities within a very specific package in
>   our caching scheme and the same classes in our instrumentation. We
>   generally have all of our entities in this package, however this one
>   which was causing the issue was the only one not included in this
>   package. The previous version of EhCache / Hibernate that we were
>   using seemed ok with this, but after upgrading it caused issues.
>
> Anyway, the entity was in the incorrect package, when I refactored it
>   and moved it into the correct package then everything worked! So it
>   was not a bug in Hibernate, just an informative exception that made it
>   difficult to track this issue down (I basically solved it by complete
>   fluke).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps somebody, but in my case it was a problem with a wrong instrumentation.

I have class 'A' and two child classes 'B' and 'C'. 'A' class has a lazy property and it is instrumented to make the lazy accessing works.

But the mistake was that I didn't instrument the child classes 'B' and 'C', therefore any access to the instrumented property from 'B' and 'C' caused the exception.

When I instrumented 'B' and 'C', the problem went away.